# How to bind dynamically created text box?

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to create pricelist for hotel. I'm having a list of dates, and list of room types in hotel. That lists can contain random number of elements. That is created dynamically, and here is the code:

```
private void CreateControls() { var colIndex = 0;        
var vrsteSoba = _Presenter.VrstaSobeDto.ToArray();

        foreach (var bindingItem in vrsteSoba)
        {

            var lbl = new Label()
            {
                Width = LABEL_WIDTH,
                Height = LABEL_HEIGHT - 5,
                Left = 10,
                Top = 30 + colIndex * (EDIT_BOX_HEIGHT + SPACE_BETWEEN_CONTROL),
                Text = bindingItem
            };
            _dataPanel.Controls.Add(lbl);
            colIndex++;
        }

        int a = 1;

        foreach (var date in _Presenter.CeneTarifa)
        {
            int y = 0;

            var panel = new Panel
            {
                Height = PANEL_HEIGHT * (vrsteSoba.Length-4),
                Width = EDIT_BOX_WIDTH,
                Left = a * (EDIT_BOX_WIDTH + SPACE_BETWEEN_CONTROL + 50),
                Top = 5
            };

            _dataPanel.Controls.Add(panel);

            var label = new Label
            {
                Height = EDIT_BOX_HEIGHT,
                Location = new Point(0, 10),                    
                Text = date.Datum,
                Margin = new Padding(0)                    
            };

            panel.Controls.Add(label);

            int index = 0;
            
            foreach (var item in date.VrstaSobeCena)
            {
                var box = new TextBox();
                panel.Controls.Add(box);
                box.Height = EDIT_BOX_HEIGHT;
                box.Width = EDIT_BOX_WIDTH;
                box.Location = new Point(0, 30 + y * (EDIT_BOX_HEIGHT + SPACE_BETWEEN_CONTROL));
                box.DataBindings.Add(new Binding(nameof(box.Text), date, date.Cena[index].Cena1)); 
                
                y++;
                index++;                    
            }
            ++a;
        }
        _dataPanel.AutoScroll = true;
    }`
```

Here is image of that representation.
[image: PriceList]

Now I'm facing a problem of data binding. I need to bind price, two way, for each text box. And I'm stuck.

I have tried to bind it to property name, but then all boxes get same value. If I try to bind it to value via index, I'm getting error
`Cannot bind to the property or column 34 on the DataSource. Parameter name: dataMember`

Code below is used to fill model that is used in presenter

```
` private void FillCenePoTarifi() { var sobeArr = VrstaSobeDto.ToArray();
 foreach (var datum in Datumi)
        {    
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
            var cene = new List<Cena>();
            foreach (var item in sobeArr)
            {
                var tarif = _Tarife.Where(x => x.SifTarife == item).FirstOrDefault();

                if (tarif != null)
                    _SastavTarife = HotelierServerLocal.Default.TarifaViewBlo.GetSastaveTarife(tarif.IdTarife);

                //proveriti ovu logiku
                var cena = _SastavTarife.Where(x => x.Cena1 != 0).Select(c => c.Cena1).FirstOrDefault();

                cene.Add(new Cena { Cena1 = cena.ToString()});
                dictionary.Add(item, cena);
            }

            var model = new CenePoTarifi
            {
                Datum = datum,
                VrstaSobeCena = dictionary,
                Cena = cene
            };

            CeneTarifa.Add(model);
        }
    }`
```

Finally here are classes that use as model.

```
` public class CenePoTarifi{
public Dictionary<string, decimal> VrstaSobeCena { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
    public string Datum { get; set; }

    private List<Cena> _Cena;


    public List<Cena> Cena
    {
        get => _Cena;
        set
        {
            _Cena = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Cena");
        }
    }

public class Cena : 
{
    private string _Cena1;
    public string Cena1
    {
        get => _Cena1;
        set 

         {
            _Cena = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Cena1");
          }


    }
}`
```

Does anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: If you bind to a list you get to see the data of the current row that is maintained by the Databinding subsystem you can't bind to all "rows" in a list. Said that it looks like a grid why don't you use a grid control.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't use grid, because I have additional items that will be added below room types, that don't belong in room type list, but are dependent of dates. Is there a way to bind boxes, outside foreach loop, after rendering happens?

Comment: @ZeljkoJerkovic your excellent question is **How to bind dynamically created text box**. Keeping a narrow focus on "one thing at a time" should attract better quality answers. (Your last comment is _also_ a good question, just consider turning that into a new post that focuses on _that_ one thing!)  Remember, also, to reduce the code down to the least it can be to reproduce the one focused question. See: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal Reproducible Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is: **How to bind dynamically created text box**. Here is one [tested](https://github.com/IVSoftware/dynamic-hotel.git) way for accomplishing that specific task.

First create some textboxes dynamically:

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    buttonRandom.Click += (sender, e) => generateRandomList();
}
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    List<TextBox> tmp = new List<TextBox>();
    for (int column = 1; column < tableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount; column++)
    {
        for (int row = 1; row < tableLayoutPanel.RowCount; row++)
        {
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox { Anchor = (AnchorStyles)0xF };
            tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(textBox, column, row);
            tmp.Add(textBox);
            textBox.KeyDown += onAnyTextBoxKeyDown;
        }
    }
    _textboxes = tmp.ToArray();
    // Generate first dataset
    generateRandomList();
}
TextBox[] _textboxes = null;
```

[image: table layout panel]

---

Then, whenever a new random list is generated, clear any old text and databindings from every `TextBox` before creating a new data binding for it.

```
public static Random Rando { get; } = new Random(2);
private void generateRandomList()
{
    // Clear ALL the data + bindings for ALL the textboxes.
    foreach (var textbox in _textboxes)
    {
        textbox.Clear();
        textbox.DataBindings.Clear();
    }
    // Generate and create new bindings
    int count = Rando.Next(1, 79);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var textbox = _textboxes[i];
        VrstaSobeCena vrstaSobeCena =
            new VrstaSobeCena{ Sobe = (Sobe)tableLayoutPanel.GetRow(textbox) };
        textbox.Tag = vrstaSobeCena;
        textbox.DataBindings.Add(
            new Binding(
                nameof(TextBox.Text),
                vrstaSobeCena,
                nameof(VrstaSobeCena.Cena),
                formattingEnabled: true,
                dataSourceUpdateMode: DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged,
                null,
                "F2"
            ));

        // TO DO
        // ADD vrstaSobeCena HERE to the Dictionary<string, decimal> VrstaSobeCena
    }
}
```

---

The classes shown in your code as binding sources may not bind correctly. One issue I noticed is that the property setters are failing to check whether the value *has actually changed* before firing the notification. Here's an example of doing that correctly. (For testing purposes I'm showing a [Minimal Reproducible Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) "mock" version of a class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.)

```
enum Sobe { APP4 = 1, APP5, STUDIO, SUP, APP6, STAND, STDNT, COMSTU, LUXSTU, APP4C, APP4L, APP62, APP6L }
class VrstaSobeCena : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    decimal _price = 100 + (50 * (decimal)Rando.NextDouble());
    public decimal Cena
    {
        get => _price;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_price, value))
            {
                _price = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    Sobe _sobe = 0;
    public Sobe Sobe
    {
        get => _sobe;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_sobe, value))
            {
                _sobe = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

---

Finally, one way to test the two-way binding is to intercept the [Enter] key.

```
private void onAnyTextBoxKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) && (sender is TextBox textbox))
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = e.Handled = true;
        VrstaSobeCena vrstaSobeCena = (VrstaSobeCena)textbox.Tag;
        string msg = $"Price for {vrstaSobeCena.Sobe} is {vrstaSobeCena.Cena.ToString("F2")}";
        BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {MessageBox.Show(msg); });
        SelectNextControl(textbox, forward: true, tabStopOnly: true, nested: false, wrap: true);
    }
}
```

[image: two-way binding]

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. You really went one step further which helped me to solve my problem! Data binding made the real difference and opened my eyes.  I'm sorry for postponed answer, but I was very ill. Thank you once again.

Comment: Glad you're feeling better and thanks for letting me know that you were able to solve your problem!

Answer (score 1):

Create a List for storing the textbox:

```
List<TextBox> lstTextbox = new List<TextBox>();
```

Create a class object that stores the values of "Date" and "room type"

```
public class RoomTypeDate
{
    public string RoomType = "";
    public string DateRange = "";
}
```

Immediately after you created the textbox, assigned the `RoomTypeDate` info to the tag, add it to `lstTextbox`.

```
foreach (var item in date.VrstaSobeCena)
{
    var box = new TextBox();
    panel.Controls.Add(box);
    box.Height = EDIT_BOX_HEIGHT;
    box.Width = EDIT_BOX_WIDTH;
    box.Location = new Point(0, 30 + y * (EDIT_BOX_HEIGHT + SPACE_BETWEEN_CONTROL));
    box.DataBindings.Add(new Binding(nameof(box.Text), date, date.Cena[index].Cena1)); 
    
    // add the box to the list
    lstTextbox.Add(box);

    // mark the box with RoomType and DateRange
    RoomTypeDate rtd = new RoomTypeDate();
    rtd.RoomType = "APP4"; // get the room type
    rtd.DateRange = "1.6 - 30.6"; // get date range
    box.Tag = rtd;

    y++;
    index++;                    
}
```

Now, to get and set the room price:

```
public void SetRoomPrice(decimal price, string roomType, string dateRange)
{
    foreach (var tb in lstTextBox)
    {
        var rtd = (RoomTypeDate)tb.Tag;

        if(rtd.RoomType == roomType && rtd.DateRange == dateRange)
        {
            tb.Text = price.ToString();
            return;
        }
    }
}

public decimal GetRoomPrice(string roomType, string dateRange)
{
    foreach (var tb in lstTextBox)
    {
        var rtd = (RoomTypeDate)tb.Tag;

        if(rtd.RoomType == roomType && rtd.DateRange == dateRange)
        {
            return Convert.ToDecimal(rt.Text);
        }
    }

    return 0m;
}
```

*code untested, might contains bugs